# Java 8 (pre-release) interface member variables

Tags: java, java-8

Are public members variables in Java 8 interfaces a feature or an implementation side-effect/defect?

This question pertains to the pre-release Java 8 build [lambda-8-b50-linux-x64-26_jul_2012.tar.gz](http://jdk8.java.net/lambda/).

Java 8 introduces new features to interfaces in the form of default methods. Casual testing with the JDK8 lambda compiler allows interfaces of this form:

```
public interface Foo {
  public int foo = 0;
  int foo() default { return foo; }
}
```

Sample implementing type:

```
public class FooImpl implements Foo {
  public int foo = 1;
}
```

This code follows the standard conventions for variable shadowing:

```
Foo f = new FooImpl();
System.out.println(f.foo());
System.out.println(f.foo);
System.out.println(new FooImpl().foo);
```

Output:

```
0
0
1
```

The documentation (JSR 335: Lambda Expressions for the Java™ Programming Language Version 0.5.1) doesn't mention member variables. I'm inclined to think the compiler is being too tolerant but perhaps I've missed something.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Public fields in interfaces are not a new features in Java 8.  If you remember that they are implicitly static and final, the results you are seeing make perfect sense.

Comment: +1 - And we can add that Java 8 could not change public interface fields to be non-static and/or non-final without breaking lots of existing code in various ways.

Comment: Doh! You are correct - I've just been declaring them static final for the last 15 years. Here is the relevant section of the JLS: [9.3. Field (Constant) Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3).