# Using Val in Scala Trait

Tags: scala

I defined trait in Scala as

```
trait checkTrait
 {
     val name:String = "male"
 }
```

As i understand when val are declared in Scala Class only accessors are generated but when i decompiled above code using JAD decompiler following gets generated

```
public interface checkTrait
{

    public abstract void checkTrait$_setter_$name_$eq(String s);
    public abstract String name();
}
```

Not able to understand what exactly is "checkTrait$*setter*$name_$eq(String s)"
is it Mutator? If it is Mutator then how they are getting generated, because as per language specification Mutators are not generated for Vals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You are right. `checkTrait$setter$name_$eq(String s)` is a **Mutator** method for initing set `name` value.

This is caused of **Scala trait** will convert to **Java interface**, and Since **Java** `interface` fields is `implicitly static and final`, but in `Scala` `trait` field need to be an field of `class` or `instance`. so this **Mutator method** is used to init the field for `checkTrait`'s subclass.

[Java 8 (pre-release) interface member variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150240/java-8-pre-release-interface-member-variables)

**Full Explanation:**

As your **decompilation**,  **Scala Compiler** convert `trait` `checkTrait` to **Java**'s `interface`. and for this **decompilation** should have another **static** `init` method in `checkTrait`, like:

```
public interface checkTrait {
  public abstract void checkTrait$_setter_$name_$eq(java.lang.String);

  public abstract java.lang.String name();

  public static void $init$(checkTrait);
    Code:

       1: ldc           #18                 // String male
       3: invokeinterface #20,  2           // InterfaceMethod checkTrait$_setter_$name_$eq:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       8: return
}
```

As you can see, this is a **static init** method with accepting a `checkTrait` instance parameter. and invoke `checkTrait$_setter_$name_$eq` this **mutator method** to initial **set value** with value: **male**.

Let us try to `extend` `checkTrait`:

```
class A extends checkTrait
```

and **decompile** this `A` class:

```
public class A implements checkTrait {
  public java.lang.String name();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: getfield      #15                 // Field name:Ljava/lang/String;
       4: areturn

  public void checkTrait$_setter_$name_$eq(java.lang.String);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: aload_1
       2: putfield      #15                 // Field name:Ljava/lang/String;
       5: return

  public A();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #24                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0
       5: invokestatic  #28                 // InterfaceMethod checkTrait.$init$:(LcheckTrait;)V
       8: return
}
```

And we can find, In the `A`'s constructor method, it will invoke the `checkTrait` `static init` method by:

```
5: invokestatic  #28                 // InterfaceMethod checkTrait.$init$:(LcheckTrait;)V
```

with pass current **instance** to init `name` field value.

So that's **Scala** way of implementing a field in **trait**.